mining pool rewards
I don't intend to apply for the mining pool reward activity, which requires USDT 30000. The activity period is 15 days, and the reward is 5 ETH. Can I use USDT, from which I withdraw profit each day, to deposit 30000 and I will get the reward? Is it really true? What do I do if I want to cancel this activity? If I don't deposit 30000 USDT within the specified 15 days, what will happen? Can I withdraw my USDT? I feel like it's a scammer.

It is an scam. If it is too good to be true then it is a scam.
